# SwiftUI - Should you use `@State var` or `let` in child view when using ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I think I've a gap in understanding what exactly `@State` means, especially when it comes to displaying contents from a `ForEach` loop.

**My scenario:** I've created minimum reproducible example. Below is a parent view with a `ForEach` loop. Each child view has a`NavigationLink`.

```
// Parent code which passes a Course instance down to the child view - i.e. CourseView
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(viewModel.courses) { course in
                    NavigationLink(course.name + " by " + course.instructor) {
                        CourseView(course: course, viewModel: viewModel)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var courses: [Course] = [
        Course(name: "CS101", instructor: "John"),
        Course(name: "NS404", instructor: "Daisy")
    ]
}

struct Course: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var instructor: String
}
```

**Actual Dilemma:** I've tried two variations for the `CourseView`, one with `let` constant and another with a `@State var` for the `course` field. Additional comments in the code below.

The one with the `let` constant successfully updates the child view when the navigation link is open. However, the one with `@State var` doesn't update the view.

```
struct CourseView: View {
    
    // Case 1: Using let constant (works as expected)
    let course: Course

    // Case 2: Using @State var (doesn't update the UI)
    // @State var course: Course

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(course.name) by \(course.instructor)")
            Button("Edit Instructor", action: editInstructor)
        }
    }
    
    // Case 1: It works and UI gets updated
    // Case 2: Doesn't work as is. 
    //    I've to directly update the @State var instead of updating the clone -
    //    which sometimes doesn't update the var in my actual project 
    //    (that I'm trying to reproduce). It definitely works here though.
    private func editInstructor() {
        let instructor = course.instructor == "Bob" ? "John" : "Bob"
        var course = course
        course.instructor = instructor
        save(course)
    }
    
    // Simulating a database save, akin to something like GRDB
    // Here, I'm just updating the array to see if ForEach picks up the changes
    private func save(_ courseToSave: Course) {
        guard let index = viewModel.courses.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == course.id }) else {
            return
        }
        viewModel.courses[index] = courseToSave
    }
}
```

**What I'm looking for** is the best practice for a scenario where looping through an array of models is required and the model is updated in DB from within the child view.

Comment: You are just initializating with var and that is the issue, with let you push view to update, you can stay with let or you can use binding! Depends on if your child gona update that value or not.

Comment: You should use @Binding

Comment: @swiftPunk Help me understand. So, when the parent array updates, the `let` version will pick up the new values. But why would `@State` not do the same? A little confused there.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson A lot of the changes do happen within the child view and parent is not updating that much. I was leaning towards the let approach.

Comment: @SiddharthKamaria: if you noticed in apple videos `State` they all use `private` it means any value wrapped with `State` it is kind of stand alone and automatic just responsible for the view that belongs, sometimes we can initialize State value but we just initialize it! After that if we try to re - initialization it would not initialized because it is already initialized! Unless we kill the view and re - initialization

Answer (score 1):

Here is a right way for you, do not forget that we do not need put logic in View! the view should be dummy as possible!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(viewModel.courses) { course in

                    NavigationLink(course.name + " by " + course.instructor, destination: CourseView(course: course, viewModel: viewModel))

                }
            }
        }
    }
}




struct CourseView: View {

    let course: Course

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(course.name) by \(course.instructor)")
            Button("Update Instructor", action: { viewModel.update(course) })
        }
    }
    

}


class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    static let shared: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    @Published var courses: [Course] = [
        Course(name: "CS101", instructor: "John"),
        Course(name: "NS404", instructor: "Daisy")
    ]
    

    func update(_ course: Course) {
        guard let index = courses.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == course.id }) else {
            return
        }

        courses[index] = Course(name: course.name, instructor: (course.instructor == "Bob") ? "John" : "Bob")
    }
    
    
}

struct Course: Identifiable {
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var instructor: String
}
```

Comment: One more thing. Reg your comment on Apple vides - I agree that `State` is supposed to be private, but I face an issue where state is not updated even when it is modified from within the child view. It is kind of hit or miss, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: It would be always works if you update a State of a view, like 100%. But I think the issue about State you told is combined with NavigationView! or NavigationLink! You may not know but those api had and has and will have for sure such buges! No surprise for me if you have such issues with NavigationView.

Comment: Hahaha, I faced the infamous 14.4 or 14.5 NavigationView closing itself issue. However, I think I got the other issue where my state is not updating. As per Apple's doc -- `You should only access a state property from inside the view’s body, or from methods called by it.` and some of my methods are accessing the state from a method not called by the view directly.